# Issues converting Hex to Short getting the wrong value

Tags: c++, casting, hex, short

I have a function that converts 2 `char` values into an `unsigned short`:

```
unsigned short ToShort(char v1, char v2) {
    unsigned short s = ((v1 << 8) | v2);
    return s;
}
```

It works most of the time, but occasionally I get a number that is not correct. As we can see, some of the numbers in my output file are around 65000 when they should be a low number. This happens for large numbers as well.

One the left, we have good output. On the right, I have my own output.

[image]

Both outputs use the same input. Bytes are read from a file and stored into an array of chars. This array contained short values. You can see the error when some of the values are put into a short.

Comment: Show an example of values that give the wrong result. That’s only about three more lines of code.

Comment: There is an image attached that has the good and bad output side by side.

Comment: I think @PeteBecker was asking for the *input* values that give the wrong answers.

Comment: ... as a guess, I'd say that you need to cast `v1` to `unsigned int` before the shift.

Comment: This gets me closer. It fixes smaller numbers. Its not working for bigger number that had the original issue. But bigger numbers that should be 1000+ are coming out under 255 now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates reading the file, populating the array, calling the function, and outputting the results.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead, or use masking to reduce those values to 8 bits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would but this code doest reduce nicely. In short, it reads, converts and outputs. Im reading without issues. Storing hex data in a char. This is confirmed by using `cout << std::hex << _someData_` to see that what im reading can be output by the script as it was stored in the original file. It looks to me that converting is the issue since I only get half of the correct values.

Comment: @MarkRansom This gets it done!!! this works! Thanks! Ive been banging my head on the walls for hours over this. Even created an account just to ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` gets a sign extension when OR'ed. Instead of `v2` you could do:

```
(v2 & 0xFF)
```

`unsigned char` would be feasible, too.

Comment: Note that sign extension only applies to signed types, and whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined.

Comment: Indeed implementation depended: the code might have worked elsewhere.